# How to deploy my Webpackered Rails app with Capistrano and Yarn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, capistrano3, yarnpkg

## Problem with capistrano and Yarn

I tried to deploy my webpackered rails app to AWS with this capistrano script,

```
namespace :webpacker do
  task :install do
    on roles(:web) do
      within release_path do
        execute "bin/yarn"
      end
    end
  end
end

after 'bundler:install', 'webpacker:install'
```

however I got the following log and deploy was failed.

```
  INFO [74b2160e] Running /usr/bin/env bin/yarn as webmaster@example.com
 DEBUG [74b2160e] Command: cd /data/example/releases/20170324031517 && ( export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.4.0" NODENV_ROOT="/usr/local/nodenv" NODENV_VERSION="7.0.0" ; /usr/bin/env bin/yarn )
 DEBUG [74b2160e]   Node version 0.10.48 is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher.
```

So, I did ssh as `webmaster` to confirm that env was correct by following shell command.

```
which node
/usr/local/nodenv/shims/node

node --version
v7.0.0

which yarn
/usr/bin/yarn

yarn --version
0.21.3
```

I assume env variables is incorrect but don't know why env variable is incorrect.

Would you teach me how to fix this?

```
Node version 0.10.48 is not supported, please use Node.js 4.0 or higher
```

#### added

When added `append :nodenv_map_bins, 'bin/yarn'`, another issue appear.

```
INFO [aab774c8] Running NODENV_ROOT=/usr/local/nodenv NODENV_VERSION=7.0.0 /usr/local/nodenv/bin/nodenv exec bin/yarn as webmaster@example.com

 DEBUG [aab774c8] Command: cd /data/example/releases/20170324175015 && ( export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" RBENV_ROOT="/usr/local/rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.4.0" NODENV_ROOT="/usr/local/nodenv" NODENV_VERSION="7.0.0" RAILS_ENV="staging" ; NODENV_ROOT=/usr/local/nodenv NODENV_VERSION=7.0.0 /usr/local/nodenv/bin/nodenv exec bin/yarn )

 DEBUG [aab774c8]   nodenv: bin/yarn: command not found
```

Comment: what this Rake/Rails command says? ```rake webpacker:yarn_install```

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that you are using Nodenv. Capistrano runs in a Non-login, Non-interactive shell: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/ptys/ As a result, Capistrano is using system Node, not the overridden version in your `.bash_profile`.

This means that you probably need to evaluate the Nodenv script as part of running commands. Thankfully, it looks like there is a Gem for that: https://github.com/platanus/capistrano-nodenv

You will probably need to add `bin/yarn` to the `:nodenv_map_bins`. Something like:

```
append :nodenv_map_bins, 'bin/yarn'
```

Comment: Thanks For your advise, however I got another issue. The problem is added above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add yarn to your path or create an alias.

There's a gem for this as well: https://github.com/ManifoldScholar/capistrano-yarn